# How to execute Netscaler commands through a remote machine via SSH connection

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, scripting

I have been trying to execute some NetScaler commands like "bind" & "unbind" through a Linux Box via an SSH Connection.
Now the Problem is, Manually we are able to enter & execute commands on NetScalar, but through SSH we are not.
Netscaler is a hardware device (or network appliance) manufactured by Citrix, which primary role is to provide Level 4 Load Balancing. It also supports Firewall, proxy and VPN functions.

if we log on to the Machine (in which NetScaler is configured), through a connection manager(Putty) we get a different prompt other than the shell. & Here we need to execute the commands like ...

unbind lb vserver VS_Netbanking_443_26 -policyName manual_checkSession

&

bind lb vserver VS_Netbanking_443_26 -policyname manual_checkSession -priority 155

which we are able to execute, 
But when we try to execute the same through script (as given below), we are not able to.

./rem_expect_con.sh $SERVER $PASSWORD `` `unbind lb vserver VS_Netbanking_443_26 -policyName manual_checkSession `` `

&

./rem_expect_con.sh $SERVER $PASSWORD `` `bind lb vserver VS_Netbanking_443_26 -policyname manual_checkSession -priority 155 `` `

Above "rem_expect_con" is a script built for Password less connection.

i have tried giving above arguments as

./rem_expect_con.sh $SERVER $PASSWORD 'bind lb vserver VS_Netbanking_443_26 -policyname manual_checkSession -priority 155'

./rem_expect_con.sh $SERVER $PASSWORD "bind lb vserver VS_Netbanking_443_26 -policyname manual_checkSession -priority 155"

`` `./rem_expect_con.sh $SERVER $PASSWORD "bind lb vserver VS_Netbanking_443_26 -policyname manual_checkSession -priority 155" `` `

But none of them are working. None of them are executing on the Netscaler.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this useful:

[How to Run the NetScaler Shell Commands from a Remote Computer](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116453)

> Additionally, you can run multiple commands separated by a semi colon and enclosed in double quotes. The following is an example of running commands to display ARP and Bridge table entries on the NetScaler appliance:
>   user@mgmnt #ssh nsroot@netscaler 'shell “nsapimgr -d allarp ; nsapimgr -d allbridge”'

I have tested this on NS10.0: Build 78.6.nc. My experience differed from the Citrix article, however. I ended up having to use this format: `user@netscaler 'showlb vserver test'`

Since you didn't post the actual error, my guess is that your script is the issue.